# How can i know how much pending connections my listening socket has?

Tags: sockets, tcp, network-programming, udp, server

I use [UDT networking API](http://udt.sourceforge.net/udt4/doc/accept.htm) to send relieable UDP data. In my application there is a server and a client, and server has listening thread which accepts incoming connections.

But i've noticed that calling `accept()` on that listening thread leads to blocking and waits for real connection.

I want to find a way skip that if there is no connection pending. How can i do it (with which option or function)

Comment: I don't understand.  If you have a separate/dedicated listening thread, why would blocking be a problem??

Comment: @MartinJames because this thread also processes all existing server clients and receives data.

Comment: Even if the pending queue could be examined, the returned count would be stale - another dozen clients could have turned up as your inspection call returned:(

Comment: @MartinJames in C#/.net there is a flag on TcpListener for example that is set in case if anyone attempts to connect. This means there is a function for this.

Comment: Well, that's a bad plan.  Change your design so as to use select() or epoll().  Either that, or use a client<>server thread per connection.

Comment: @Joker It doesn't mean that at all. A flag is not the same thing as a count of the number of pending connections. A flag can be implemented with `select().`

Comment: @EJP yep, currently checking for incoming connections via `select` on server socket. This is solution to my original question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to know *how many* clients are waiting to be accepted.  However, you can use `select()`, `poll()`, or `epoll()` to detect if there are *any* clients waiting (the listening socket will be in a reading state in that condition) before then calling `accept()`.

Comment: epoll is right direction, i should use it from the beggining instead of any loops or selects.